# Making all application windows stay fullscreen on relaunch

Tags: macos, spaces, mission-control, fullscreen, xcode

I usually have 4+ fullscreen windows open whenever I use Xcode 4. When I quit Xcode, and reopen it, only one or two of the windows open as fullscreen, and the rest all open in a single desktop as normal windows. (I think the behavior is the same with Chrome and probably other apps to.)

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this yet, but did a quick search and there is a free add-on called Maximizer available.

It may not be build into Lion yet (as far as I know) but this will get you close for what you want :-)

http://chpwn.com/apps/maximizer.html

Comment: How would this help? Xcode 4 has built in fullscreen support, and I don't see how this software would fix the problem with reopening Xcode.